# How to update scripts with bower?

Tags: bower

> I've created an issue/question about this on
>   [Github](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/971) but it didn't
>   receive any attention, except just more people wondering the same
>   thing, so I decided to try my luck on StackOverflow.

**Q: How do you update your bower ?**

My problem:
I had Packery 1.0.6 Installed and when I ran `bower update` it just scanned the directories and **didn't update anything at all**.

Then I edited the bower.json file and removed Packery 1.0.6 from dependencies and ran:

`bower install packery`

That confused bower a little, and it asked me which version I wanted - I selected 1.1.2 and now I have 1.1.2.

Why didn't it update to 1.1.2 in the first place ? How can I trust Bower that I have the latest version of everything installed ?

On top of that, running `bower update packery` doesn't work as well. I thought bower is supposed to be the magical package manager that takes out the hassle of keeping my packages up to date, but as it turns out - it doesn't do much besides installing new packages...

Comment: What did you have in your `bower.json` file?

Comment: Whatever bower generated for me with `bower install jquery.mylib.js --save`

Does bower update all scripts just fine for you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bower will automatically install your packages with the notation `~x.x.x`.  It's based on [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) and it's package notation.

It doesn't update everything, because it will respect your app's requirements.  In your case:

```
~1.0.6 := >=1.0.6-0 <1.1.0-0
```

The change from the `~1.0` to `~1.1` could potentially be breaking, and Bower is not willing to update you package unless you are ok with it.  Consider it more of a protection.

If you have your `bower.json` file set as

```
>= 1.0.6
```

It should get you nothing less than 1.0.6.

Check out the ranges section on [this page](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
So bower is going to update to 1.0.99, but not to 1.1.0 ? Is there any way that I can force an update easily (without editing files) ?

Comment: Not on it's own.  You can always pass the version number like this `bower install packery#1.1.2 --save` to update the json file.  It behaves this way to protect your deps, and keep you from jacking up your app due to a breaking update.